# Autofill Formula Updating Wrong Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet where i want to copy the following formula to all rows in VBA:

```
=INDEX('Sales Orders'!A:Z,SMALL(IF('Sales Orders'!A:A='Service Requests'!A2,ROW('Sales Orders'!A:Z)),ROW('Sales Orders'!1:1))*1,21)
```

In VBA it looks like this:

```
Range("BD2").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
"=INDEX('Sales Orders'!C[-55]:C[-30],SMALL(IF('Sales Orders'!C[-55]='Service Requests'!RC[-55],ROW('Sales Orders'!C[-55]:C[-30])),ROW('Sales Orders'!R[-1]))*1,21)"
```

Then this is what i have to copy it down to the last row:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "BC").End(xlUp).Row, "BD"))
```

So the row below now looks up `A3` in 'Service Requests' which is intended, but it also changes the instance it is looking for in 'Sales Orders' to `2:2` - this is not intended.

How can i get it to change the `A` value but not the instance value?

Comment: Use `ROW('Sales Orders'!R1)` not `ROW('Sales Orders'!R[-1])`

Comment: @Rory , will build on you to be more informative for other readers, the [#] with RC notation indicates "in respect to".  So If you're in cell B2 (R2C2), and want to reference cell A2 (R2C1), you would have in cell B2 =RC[-1].

Comment: @rory, thanks to both of you so much for your help, what i did in the end was put $1:$1 as cyril advised this would fix the columns, when i copied this through into VBA it showed as R1 like you said Rory so both were valid answers.

Comment: @cyril - see above, couldn't add both of you in one comment

Comment: @Harwood95 Copy; glad that worked.  I had deleted my answer after seeing Rory's comment, as I took an incorrect approach overall.  Luckily you got the information for *Ensure you have the correct "fixed" values, such as source ranges where A1 is dynamic row/column and A$1 is dynamic column but fixed row.* before I deleted!